# Number of times oobCode can be used in Firebase's verifyPasswordResetCode()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My application uses Firebase for authentication and as a DMZ with the server (listening to Firebase changes). To reset passwords, I allow requests for security questions and security answer verification to get to the server freely through Firebase (Rules for those keys are true).

Since it is open, anyone can write to Firebase (make a request to the server). This leads me to think that a brute force attack might be possible. Hence my question, is there a limit to the number of times an oobCode can be verified using `firebase.auth().verifyPasswordResetCode()`?

---

Assume an attacker has access to the user's device and thus email.

The password reset process is the following:

1. Attacker enters email to receive a reset link.
2. Reset link sent to email.
3. Link redirects to app and calls verifyPasswordResetCode().
4. On callback from 3, a request is sent to the server for a security 
   question.

And so on. I would like to know if there is a limit and if Firebase will block too many verifyPasswordResetCode().

Comment: The attacker would still need to know the emails. The requests would fail when the emails do not exist. So it doesn't seem like a very practical attack. Unless you are exposing other users' emails in your app.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: If the attacker has access to the user's device/email, your user has bigger problems. The user can still access their email from a separate device and try to recover from there. You may need to add some other means of recovery too. As the app owner you can always bypass this via the Firebase Console or by building something (secret questions for the account) using the Firebase Admin SDK.